# How to update widget state built inside FutureBuilder

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget, flutter-futurebuilder

Before, I used `ListBuilder` to generate a list of 70 numbers and it worked but it took a long time to generate the 70 numbers into custom widgets and also when I tapped a number just to change the background color state, it took a couple of milliseconds before the state being changed.

[image: ow]

Now I am using a `FutureBuilder` to be able to load the screen while waiting for the generated 70 integers. But when I tap on the ball number, the background color is not updated ... It's like `setState()` is not working in Future ListBuilder.

This question: "**[Flutter - How to update state (or value?) of a Future/List used to build ListView (via FutureBuilder)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57224251/flutter-how-to-update-state-or-value-of-a-future-list-used-to-build-listvie)**" is very similar, but it did not solve my problem.

Here is the code I have in the build method

```
Flexible(
                child:FutureBuilder<List<Widget>>(
                  future: ballNumbers,
                  builder: (context, snapshot){
                    if(snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done){
                      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                    }
                    if(snapshot.hasError){
                      return Center(child: Text("An error has occured"));
                    }
                    List<Widget> balls = snapshot.data ?? [];
                    return GridView.count(
                      crossAxisCount: 9,
                      children: balls,
                    );
                  }
                )
```

Here is how I start the state for the function:

```
Future<List<Widget>> ballNumbers;
List<int> picks = []; 

@override
void initState() {
    ballNumbers = getBallNumbers();
});

  Future<List<Widget>> getBallNumbers() async {
    return List.generate(limitBallNumber,(number){
      number = number + 1;
      return Padding(
        padding:EdgeInsets.all(2.5),
        child:Ball(
          number : number,
          size: ballWidth,
          textColor:(picks.contains(number)) ? Colors.black : Colors.white,
          ballColor: (picks.contains(number)) ? Style.selectedBallColor : Style.ballColor,
          onTap:(){
            setState((){
                picks.contains(number) ? picks.remove(number) : picks.add(number);
            });
          }
        )
      );
    });
  }
```

UPDATED: Here is the class the `Ball` widget

```
class Ball extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color ballColor;
  final Color textColor;
  final double size;
  final double fontSize;
  final int number;
  final VoidCallback onTap;

  Ball({Key key, @required this.number, 
    this.textColor, 
    this.ballColor,
    this.onTap,
    this.size = 55.0,
    this.fontSize = 14,
  }) : super(key : key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: size,
      width: size,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          colors: [
            Style.secondaryColor,
            ballColor != null ? ballColor : Style.ballColor,
          ],
          begin: Alignment.bottomLeft,
          end: Alignment.topRight
        )
      ),
      child: FlatButton(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
        child: Container(
          child: Text(
            number.toString().length > 1 ? number.toString() : "0" + number.toString(),
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: fontSize,
              color: textColor != null ? textColor : Colors.white
            ),
          ),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
          decoration:BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            border: Border.all(color: textColor != null ? textColor : Colors.white,  width: 1),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32),
          )
        ),
        color: Colors.transparent,
        onPressed: onTap,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `getBallNumbers` is only being called once in `initState`, so when `picks` is updated, it doesn't matter because `getBallNumbers` isn't called again to update the colors being passed to the `Ball` widgets.

A simple fix would be to call `getBallNumbers` in your `build` with `future: getBallNumbers()`, but this would lead to the `CircularProgressIndicator` being shown on every click as the `List` regenerates.

However, ideally, you should be handling all of the color changing within the state of each `Ball` so that you're not forced to rebuild that `List` on every click. And to maintain a `List` of selected numbers within the parent widget's `State`, you should pass a callback to each ball that adds and removes their number from the `List` in the parent.

---

**Rough example:**

Ball class(modified to be stateful and removed parameters that became unecessary; active state is now stored within the ball instead of solely in the parent):

```dart
class Ball extends StatefulWidget {
  final double size;
  final double fontSize;
  final int number;
  final VoidCallback toggleBall;
  final bool initialActiveState;

  Ball({Key key, @required this.number, 
    this.toggleBall,
    this.size = 55.0,
    this.fontSize = 14,
    this.initialActiveState,
  }) : super(key : key);

  _BallState createState() => _BallState();
}

class _BallState extends State<Ball> {
  bool isActive;
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    isActive = widget.initialActiveState;
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: widget.size,
      width: widget.size,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          colors: [
            Style.secondaryColor,
            isActive ? Style.selectedBallColor : Style.ballColor,
          ],
          begin: Alignment.bottomLeft,
          end: Alignment.topRight
        )
      ),
      child: FlatButton(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
        child: Container(
          child: Text(
            widget.number.toString().length > 1 ? widget.number.toString() : "0" + widget.number.toString(),
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: widget.fontSize,
              color: isActive ? Colors.black : Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
          decoration:BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            border: Border.all(color: isActive ? Colors.black : Colors.white,  width: 1),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32),
          )
        ),
        color: Colors.transparent,
        onPressed: () {
          if(!isActive && widget.activeBallList.length >= 7) {
            return;
          }
          setState(() {
            isActive = !isActive;
          });
          widget.activeBallList.contains(widget.number) ? widget.activeBallList.remove(widget.number) : widget.activeBallList.add(widget.number);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Parent class(the only part that needs to be modified is the parameters for `Ball`):

```dart
Future<List<Widget>> getBallNumbers() async {
  return List.generate(limitBallNumber,(number){
    number = number + 1;
    return Padding(
      padding:EdgeInsets.all(2.5),
      child: Ball(
        number: number,
        size: ballWidth,
        initialActiveState: picks.contains(number),
        activeBallList: picks,
      )
    );
  });
}
```

Comment: Can you please show an example based on what you explained?

Comment: @Lemayzeur For the "ideal" solution? Also where are you calling `setState`?

Comment: Yes please. I am a little new to Flutter. but it seems that your solution is going to work

Comment: Ow sorry! I missed it in the code, I call it in the onTap function callback

Comment: @Lemayzeur Yeah I can make a sample. Just letting you know it'll take a while. Can you show `Ball` class as well?

Comment: Just updated the code, Ball class added. Thank you!

Comment: @Lemayzeur I posted the example. Not as much needed to be changed in the parent class as I originally thought, so my previous explanation might've been a bit over-complicated. I can't really test this so let me know of the result.

Comment: Hello Not A Bot, Your solution works like charm. But there is a limitation of 7 balls, I see that now I can select without that limit... do you know how to have that limitation up to 7 balls selected? picks must have at more 7 balls, and after that the user can not change any balls

Comment: @Lemayzeur So if you try to generate a `List` of more than 7 balls it just stops working? The active state of each balls just stops changing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218687/discussion-between-lemayzeur-and-not-a-bot).